# Show the type of a function

Tags: types, scheme, racket

But in Racket, the interpreter does not show the type:

```
> cadr
#<procedure:cadr>
```

Is there a way to show the type of a function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Racket is an untyped language, so there's no equivalent of this information there.  However, if you use [Typed Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/), a typed dialect of Racket, you'll get exactly this kind of information:

```
-> string-append
- : (String * -> String)
#<procedure:string-append>
```

Comment: More specifically, OCaml is statically-typed, while Racket is dynamically-typed

Comment: @newacct, I don't like the term dynamically typed -- I don't think it really means anything the way people use it.  I'll stick with my statement that Racket is untyped, which is *not* intended as a criticism of Racket (I'm one of the developers of Racket), but as a simple descriptive statement.

Comment: Like it or not, but dynamically/statically typed languages are differ from untyped. For example, in untyped awk you can easiy concatenate strings and numbers while in dynamically scheme/racket you'll get runtime error.

Comment: @paul The behavior of operations like `(+ 3 "hi")` is entirely about the meaning of the `+` operation, and has nothing to do with types.  You can easily create a type system that allows this behavior, and give it an appropriate result type.

Comment: @SamTobin-Hochstadt Sure, you can redefine "+" to accept number and string, but this do not refer to case and do not proof I was wrong. This discussion is all about term definition. For me is better to distinguish static/dynamic typed languages from untyped as it gives you some clarification about language. I DO see difference between awk and scheme in terms of "type".

Comment: @paul, your claim seems to be that if we change the behavior of `+` in Scheme to be more like JavaScript, then it becomes an untyped instead of dynamically-typed language.  But `+` is just a function in Scheme, and I can write a different one that behaves the way you describe.  Thus, Scheme is already an untyped language, by your argument.

Comment: @SamTobin-Hochstadt, If one will change all (builtin) functions in Haskell to be `Just a -> Just a` will it became untyped? If typed language looks like untyped and quacks like a untyped then it untyped. Btw, if you redefine "+" this will be new lambda and not bulting what I talk about ;)

Comment: If Haskell didn't impose a static check on programs to make sure they're type correct, then it would be untyped.  Just like Racket.  Also, the built-in/user-defined distinction is meaningless here.  But this discussion is long past usefulness.